# How to use TMA related events like "topdown-fe-bound" in perf-5.14?

Tags: intel, perf

The environment we use are as follows: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8468VL + Kernel 5.14 + CentOS 7 + perf-5.14

We have the following four different result:

> sudo perf -a -e topdown-fe-bound -- sleep 1
>
> <not supported> topdown-fe-bound

> sudo perf -a -e slots,topdown-fe-bound -- sleep 1
>
> 14,001,930,708 slots
>
> <not supported> topdown-fe-bound

> sudo perf -a -e '{topdown-fe-bound}' -- sleep 1
>
> <not supported> topdown-fe-bound

> sudo perf -a -e '{slots,topdown-fe-bound}' -- sleep 1
>
> 511,115,940 slots
>
> 100,354,686 topdown-fe-bound

It seems that *topdown-fe-bound* works only with both *slot* and *the -e '{eventname}' format*.

What is the reason for this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`topdown-fe-bound` event needs these two special requirements because:

The Fixed counter 3 must be the leader of the group, that is, the SLOTS event must be the leader of a TopDowngroup, the second event of the group is the sampling event.
Please refer to [paragraphs from Row52 and Row 296](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f1fcbaa18b28dec10281551dfe6ed3a3ed80e3d6/tools/perf/Documentation/topdown.txt#LL61C6-L61C6).

Similar interdependence or format requirement for other events and which document should we refer to:

There isn't a uniformed document for this kind of requirements. You need to check such events seperately in kernel code. To simplify your usage, it is recommended to refer to [Intel Perfspect events list](https://github.com/intel/PerfSpect/blob/master/events/spr.txt). This is a more easy and direct way than using kernle wrappered event name.